# What does it mean if a User Log indicates no User Agent?

Tags: user-agent

I am helping a friend run their online game and looking out for cheaters and the logs sometime come in blank for their user agents.

Like this.

2019-03-15 15:36:12 143.176.107.114     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36

2019-03-15 15:35:38 143.176.107.114

2019-03-15 15:29:31 143.176.107.114

2019-03-15 15:25:57 143.176.107.114     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36

I have not seen it on any other accounts. Any guesses ?

Comment: The user agent is provided "voluntarily" by the client. Those that adhere to web standards will always provide theirs. However, it's easy to alter a client to not provide a user agent or to provide one that's not real. In a former job, I always set a "custom" user agent so I could easily filter my own traffic in the logs. Changing a user agent to an empty string is just as easy as changing it to read `Mozilla/9.9(MSDOS 5.1; iOS; x64)`

Comment: Yeah. I am aware and hoping the other cheaters do not realize this, however, this user only has it missing sometimes. Weird that if he was blocking it, he would not just do it all the time.